# Help with likelihood ratio statistics and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

In [MIT's Foundations of Computational and Systems Biology lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/7-91j-foundations-of-computational-and-systems-biology-spring-2014/index.htm), lecture 8: RNA-sequence analysis there is a section on hypothesis testing.

They have two different hypotheses/models for the same dataset - the null (H0) that the dataset came from two independent Gaussians and the alternative (H1) that the dataset came from two correlated Gaussians. Picture below:

[image: Picture]

The lecturer adds that since alternative hypotheses, typically, are more complex and a more complex model will always explain data better. So the lecturer adds that he is going to compute a test statistic. And the test statistic is going to be a function of the observed data. And it's 2 times the log of the probability of the observed data given H1 over the probability of the observed data given H0.

[image: Statistic]

He then concludes that the sampling distribution for the above mentioned test statistic is chi-squared distribution with the degrees of freedom equal to the difference of free parameters in the two hypotheses. H0 has 4 parameters - two means and two variances, while H1 has 6 parameters - two means and four covariances. He concludes that sampling distribution for the test statistic is then chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom.

I have three questions:

1. Why is the likelihood ratio statistic equal to two times the log of the probability of the observed data given H1 over the probability of the observed data given H0?
2. Why is H1 described by 6 free parameters instead of 5 - the covariance matrix should be symmetric, if we know sigma12 we know sigma21?
3. Why is the sampling distribution of this test statistic chi-squared?

Comment: The statistic in (1) is *not* the likelihood ratio statistic. The likelihood ratio statistic would be $\Lambda=L_0/L_1$ (the ratio of two likelihoods, naturally); the statistic in (1) is $-2\log\Lambda$, and minus twice the log of a thing is not the thing you started with. (There's a good reason to take minus twice the log, which an answer would probably address in answering question 3, but there's not a good reason to flat out call it the likelihood ratio statistic)

Comment: @Glen_b Why isn't there a good reason to call minus twice the log of ratio of  two likelihoods a likelihood ratio *statistics*? Or to rephrase, why would it be better to call likelihood ratio a likelihood ratio *statistic*? Furthermore, whenever I search for likelihood ratio statistic I see it defined as log of ratio, as opposed to ratio. For example [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT18_443S15_LEC10.pdf).